# Reading a datetime column with a null data SqlCeDataReader?

Tags: .net, sql-server-ce

What's the way to read a column that might have a null datetime value in SQLCe?

Right now i have this

```
SqlCeDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
DateTime? shapeFileSQLDateTime = (DateTime?)reader["ShapeFileTimestamp"];//ok b/c has data
DateTime? mdbSQLDateTime = (DateTime?)reader["CreatedTimestamp"];  //throws exception b/c is null data in cell
```

I can wrap it in an exception handler, but I don't want to.

I'm using C# and vs2010

Comment: Same issue, thanks for the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DateTime? mdbSQLDateTime = reader["CreatedTimestamp"] == DBNull.Value ? null : (DateTime?)reader["CreatedTimestamp"]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTime? mdbSQLDateTime =  reader["CreatedTimestamp"] == null ? null :  (DateTime?)reader["CreatedTimestamp"];
```